# Find the least squares solution of the linear system......

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

Hi I'm looking for the least squares solutions of....

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1&-1 \\ -1&2 \\ -1&0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x\\y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \\ 5\end{pmatrix} $$

So Assuming this goes by $ A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$

Then using.... $A^T A \vec{x} = A^T \vec{b} $

$$ \begin{pmatrix}  1&-1&-1 \\ -1&2&0 \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} 1&-1 \\ -1&2 \\ -1&0 \end{pmatrix} \vec{x}= \begin{pmatrix}  1&-1&-1 \\ -1&2&0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \\ 5\end{pmatrix}  $$

Which solves to be 
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 3&-3 \\ -3&5 \end{pmatrix} \vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix} -6 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix} $$

which i solve to get 
$$ \vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix} -7/3 \\ 3/2 \end{pmatrix}  $$

Comment: Why are X and y in your solution? You should get just one vector.

Comment: Ah that's right i'll take them off now

Comment: You haven´t applied the method of least squares. Beside this your equation has no solution.

Comment: @calculus The solution to the linear least squares problem is given by the normal equations.

Comment: @ian Sure, I agree.

Comment: @calculus Which is what the OP set up...

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Check your algebra. I get $\begin{pmatrix} -6 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}$ for the constant of the linear system.

Comment: @ian That´s true. Ouch.

Comment: @Ja72 the question is "find the least squares solution of the system"

Answer (score 4):

Since you are only asking for the solution...

$$ \left( \begin{vmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \\ -1 & 0 \end{vmatrix}^\intercal \begin{vmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \\ -1 & 0 \end{vmatrix} \right) \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}  = \left( \begin{vmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \\ -1 & 0 \end{vmatrix}^\intercal \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix} \right) $$

$$ \begin{vmatrix} 3 & -3 \\ -3 & 5 \end{vmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -6 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix} $$

$$ \begin{pmatrix} x = -\frac{5}{2} \\ y = -\frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: Thanks so i was on the right track but just made a calculation error?

Comment: Based on the information given yes.

Answer (score 2):

The normal equations are correct:
$$
\mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} x = \mathbf{A}^{*}b.
$$
The error is in the solution which should be
$$
 x = \left( \mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{*}b.
$$
The inverse is
$$
\left( \mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} \right)^{-1} = \frac{1} {6}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 3 \\
 3 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which provides
$$
 x = -\frac{1}{2}
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
  5 \\
  1
\end{array}
\right).
$$